# Fancybox is not working properly

Tags: fancybox

I have a problem that I am unable to solve. When I click on the picture use the fancybox to enlarge and visualize the picture, so far so good but when I click he's throwing me to the top of the page and this is not correct , does anyone know how to revolve it?

Link project
http://codetek.com.br/~barbosa/

Comment: Download the latest master from here https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/archive/master.zip where that bug has been fixed

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible solutions, either with modifying fancybox `CSS` or with fancybox `helpers`

In your case scenario, when the image clicked and opened page scroll to top while image show,

I recommend add following CSS property in `fancybox-lock body` selector in fancybox css.

```
.fancybox-lock body {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

other solution with `helpers` is

```
helpers: {
    overlay: {
      locked: false
    }
}
```

Sidenote: you are using id to trigger fancybox `$("#single_2").fancybox({` and in HTML

```
<div class="circle-box">
    <a id="single_2" href="portfolio/img2.jpg" title="none1">
        <img src="img2.jpg" alt="none1" />
    </a>
</div>
<div class="circle-box">
    <a id="single_2" href="portfolio/img3.jpg" title="none1">
        <img src="img3.jpg" alt="none1" />
    </a>
</div>
```

id's must be unique so change fancybox trigger to `$(".single_2").fancybox({` and in HTML

```
<div class="circle-box">
    <a class="single_2" href="portfolio/img2.jpg" title="none1">
        <img src="portfolio/img2.jpg" alt="none1" />
    </a>
</div>
<div class="circle-box">
    <a class="single_2" href="portfolio/img3.jpg" title="none1">
        <img src="portfolio/img3.jpg" alt="none1" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Same changes for the rest of the images.